# SubWebFolder and mutliple bin folders with Website model?

Tags: asp.net, web, projects

I am looking for some advice on how what is the best approach to subweb folders and having mutliple bin folders in the WebSite Project model. For adding new pages at a later stage without recompiling the core files of a website and without building a full fledged Plug-in framework api. I am aware of being able to drop in the compiled dlls into the main bin folder and to just copy over the new page files to a sub folder but I am looking for a more organized file/folder approach.

Here is the how it was done with WAP: 
[Moving the Code-Behind Assemblies/DLLs to a different folder than /BIN with ASP.NET 1.1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=4d0ef4fb-f8ae-4355-a658-3c0432c98dbe#commentstart)

[Multiple /bin folders in ASP.NET](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000131.html)

I should also mention that I see that I can still do it the old way with the website project model by making the adjustment to the config section mentioned here but I was wondering if that has any side affects.

[AssemblyBinding in Web Config and XMLNS](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2006/11/15/AssemblyBinding-in-Web-Config-and-XMLNS.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to copy new DLL's or new sources to your site?  Note that for sources, the best place in web sites is the App_Code folder.  In there, you can create any arbitrary folder structure that you like, and it will all be built at runtime into an assembly.  Then, every page gets a reference to that assembly and is able to use types from there.

Comment: The website project is pre-compiled and updateable, so the app_code folder is compiled.
What I am trying to do is copy new add-on pages into a sub folder with thier own bin folders to keep everything more organized vs. just adding the new aspx files to a new folder under the root of the appliation and than throwing the compiled code for these new pages into the root application bin folder.